# Dropdown menu items inheriting parent menu item border CSS issue

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have created a drop down menu however i have an issue with some of the sub menu items inheriting the CSS of the parent menu item.

In particualr, the sub menu items are inheriting the blue border of the parent, and the light blue background colour when hovering over the sub menu item.

I have added a red border, and can see that, but the blue still appears, also, i have added a 'red' hover class but this is not being triggered.

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/W2zrn/

HTML:

```
<nav class="site-nav">
    <ul class="menu-nav wrap menu menu--hor">
        <ul id="main-nav">
            <li class="menu-nav--home">
                <a href="index.html" title="home"></a>
            </li>
            <li id="nav-dropdown" class="drop-down"> <a>Link 1</a>

                <ul class="visuallyhidden">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" title="title">Link Two Sub One</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" title="title">Link Two Sub Two</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" title="title">Link Two Sub Three</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a>Link 2</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Look into child and sibling selectors: http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Answer (score 1):

To remove the sub menu items inhering the blue border of the parent, change this

```
.menu-nav li li a, .menu-nav a {
  border-right: 1px solid #0d63ba;
}
```

to

```
.menu-nav > li a {
  border-right: 1px solid #0d63ba;
}
```

What this does is apply the blue border only to the anchor tags of the immediate child elements(li items) of the `ul menu-nav`.

For the red background hover to happen change this

```
.drop-down ul li:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

to

```
.drop-down ul li:hover a {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats part way there for the red background, but still seeing a blue border. I think it is because i still have .menu-nav li a {
  border-right: 1px solid #083d72;
}

Comment: ignore my comment, now works.. i had added an extra a on the class above by mistake.

Comment: just realised this doesnt entirely work.. By having .menu-nav > la a.. It removes the #0d63ba shade from the main menu elements. Example of updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/W2zrn/6/

Comment: @OamPsy .drop-down ul li a{border-right:0;} this should definitely help you

Answer (score 1):

check out this i have updated your fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/W2zrn/5/

added small code

```
#nav-dropdown li a {
  border: medium none;
padding: 0 0 0 10%;
width:100%;
}
#nav-dropdown li {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
}
```